# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 - Folder and Report Security

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there any way I can list (either using a `SSRS` report or querying through SQL code), the `Username` or `Group` security that has been assigned against root folders, sub-folders or reports ?

I've been asked to identify as an audit, which `AD` groups have access to all root folders and sub-folders within that root folder, or even down to the individual report level - of who has access!

How do I accomplish this request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can query the ReportServer database for this information, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    CASE [Catalog].[Type]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Folder'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Report'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Resource'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Linked Report'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Report Model'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Report Part'       
    END AS CatalogType,
    [Catalog].[Type]
    --, [Catalog].ItemID 
    ,[Catalog].Name
    , Roles.RoleName
    , Users.UserName
FROM PolicyUserRole 
INNER JOIN Roles ON PolicyUserRole.RoleID = Roles.RoleID
INNER JOIN Policies ON PolicyUserRole.PolicyID = Policies.PolicyID
INNER JOIN Users ON PolicyUserRole.UserID = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN [Catalog] ON PolicyUserRole.PolicyID = [Catalog].PolicyID
ORDER BY 
    1
    , [Catalog].ItemID
    , [Catalog].Name
    , Roles.RoleName
    , Users.UserName
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what Catalog type 3 represents - I think it can be used for any other resource not listed, e.g. uploaded files. There's very little documentation on this. Also note that querying ReportServer database directly is not supported by Microsoft and the schema and/or meaning of these values could change in later versions.

Comment: @Nathan - are these types defined in ReportServer somewhere?

Comment: @TrailJon Back when I wrote this, they weren't - not sure about more recent versions.